# Check if items are overlapping

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, overlap, collider

I have a few rooms which are placed randomly so I have to check if a room is overlapping. The rooms have a size of 10x10 and are for test reasons placed exactly side by side (they don't overlap in the scene). The Floor is a Transform which consists out of 1 or more Transforms (in this case out of one square but for other forms it it could be 2 or more).

To check if they are overlapping I have this function which doesn't work. Debug log is always something between 3 and 61..

```
public bool Overlapping()
{
    //Lists for the position and of the size of each floor transform
    List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    List<Vector3> sizes = new List<Vector3>();
    //Check if floor consists out of more than 1 transform
    if (Floor.childCount > 0)
        foreach (Transform t in Floor)
        {
            positions.Add(t.position);
            sizes.Add(t.lossyScale);
        }
    else
    {
        positions.Add(Floor.position);
        sizes.Add(Floor.lossyScale);
    }

    //Save old room pos and move it out of the way
    Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
    this.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 100, 0);

    //Check if any floor transform would overlap
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
        //Make overlap box visible
        GameObject rec = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        rec.transform.localScale = sizes[i];
        rec.transform.localPosition = positions[i];
        rec.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

        //Returns the colliders which are overlapping
        if (Physics.OverlapBox(positions[i], sizes[i] / 2).Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log(Physics.OverlapBox(positions[i], sizes[i] / 2).Length);
            //return this room to it's old position
            this.transform.position = position;
            return true;
        }
    }

    //return this room to it's old position
    this.transform.position = position;
    return false;
}
```

By the way for anyone reading (2/2016) `OverlapBox` is a brand-new call Unity just added to the latest verion.

**Edit**: As suggested by Joe I made the OverlapBox 'visible', but they seem to be in the correct positions and in the correct sizes (Red is my room, gray are the colliders)....

[image: Colliders]

Comment: Just BTW. a transform is just a "point".  you mean colliders, Bounds or whatever

Comment: OverlapBox: [Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html)

Comment: Isn't a transform a representation of the visible part of an GameObject?

Comment: not at all, `Transform` holds the position (and indeed scale etc) of any `GameObject`.  note that often a game GameObject will not even have a visible area, it could be just a Component or whatever - nothing to do with anything visible.

Comment: ATransform is just a class containing a position, a rotation and scale. It is basically a point in space. Then you have the mesh made of many points that are positioned in space based on that Transform. The mesh via the renderer is the visual part of the GameObject (fairly simplified).  An empty game object is a Transform, nothing else.

Comment: Okay, thank's for that. May you know an better way to check if two objects are overlapping? I already tried it with the OverlapSphere which seems to work, but isn't applikable for more complex forms than a square...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now. Each OverlapBox was placed correctly, but they where still colliding, because they were 'too close' to the object. This change fixed it:

```
if (Physics.OverlapBox(positions[i], new Vector3(sizes[i].x - 0.01f, sizes[i].y - 0.01f, sizes[i].z - 0.01f) / 2, rotations[i]).Length > 0)
```