# How do I access GameObject components from a transform that is attached to a different GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change certain GameObjects from one specific GameObject in Unity.. To try to explain:

I have a square with a square_script attached. In the script I have a Transform[] positions. Inside of Unity I have added 5 GameObjects as children of my square and drag them into the positions array. I will then set the transforms so that there is one in the center of the square, one which is one squares length to the right, one above, one below and one to the left.

I want to add other Squares on top of those transforms, so that then I click the center Square it changes any square that is on top of those transforms.

To maybe make it easier to understand, I am trying to make a "Lights Out"-like game. It is all in 2D as well. How can I do this?

This picture is my example. I want to add other blue squares to overlap those green diamonds so that I can change them through code. I need to figure out how you can change something through code on an object overlapping those diamonds.

[image]

Comment: You should make an attempt at the design you have conceived and show us the code if you have a problem with it.

Comment: I hope that clarifies it a little!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if items are overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254059/check-if-items-are-overlapping) or [Using Physics.OverlapBox in Unity 2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884571/using-physics-overlapbox-in-unity-2d)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard to follow, but I think the most basic question you are asking is - How do I get a GameObject from a Transform reference?

For this, you can use `transform.gameObject` to get this reference. From there, you are now at the GameObject level again so you should be able to find any components, methods, scripts, etc. that are on that GameObject.

Comment: Sorry if I am making it more confusing than it probably is. Will transform.gameObject only get the reference for that transform position? 

How would you access a different gameObject from that position. So if I were to add another GameObject seperate from the first square and overlap a diamond would that still work?

I guess what I'm really asking is how do you check if there are other gameobjects in the area of your gameobject and how would I access their script.

Comment: Technically that's correct but unnecessary .. you can also directly use `GetComponent` as this is also implemented in `MonoBehaviour` which your script inherits from.

Comment: I'll try to make this explicit to avoid confusion. Each of your GameObjects (parent and children) have their own transform and gameObject references. If your script is on the parent object, you can access the childrens' gameObject reference via the transform array. Something like `myTransformArray[2].gameObject`. @derHugo is correct, you can just use `myTransformArray[2].GetComponent<MyComponent>()` as well. It really just depends on what you're doing and what your preference is.